# Source code for projects using these 4 asp.net/mvc/silverlight and MS SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight

Could anyone guide me where could I get some working projects for learning which use all of these:
1. ASP.NET 2. MVC 3. Silverlight and 4. MS SQL in  back end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this is a project from a great italian group.

[Model Virtual Casting](http://modelvirtualcasting.codeplex.com/)

```
Model Virtual Casting è un'applicazione d'esempio che utilizza il .NET Framework 4.1, Silverlight 4.0, ASP.NET 4.0, MVC 3.0, WPF, WCF, RIA Services, Azure, Windows Phone 7, Unity 2.0 e MEF.
```

Translated

```
Model Virtual Casting is a sample application that use .NET Framework 4.1, Silverlight 4.0, ASP.NET 4.0, MVC 3.0, WPF, WCF, RIA Services, Azure, Windows Phone 7, Unity 2.0 e MEF.
```

Hope it helps